# MultiCrops in same image

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv

I ve an image which has 6 images within it..I ve the task of cropping the 6 images out of this image..

Currently I follow this procedure..
1. Save copy of original image
2. Crop the image to get first image using any tool(Picasa)
3. Save the cropped image as image 1
4. Open the original to crop for image 2
5. Repeat this 6 times

Is there a way in which I can extract out all the 6 images in one go? Multi-cropping?

Comment: If this question has been successfully answered, consider selecting the official answer by clicking on the checkbox near it. If not, consider adding your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You need to get familiarized with the ROI [(Region of Interest)](http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Region_of_Interest_%28ROI%29) concept.

[This **C** example](http://areshopencv.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/region-of-interest-selection-roi.html) shows how to set a ROI in an image. Basically it sets a ROI in a frame from the camera, creates a new image from it, does some processing (invert colors) in the image and then copies the image back to the original frame for display.

[This **Python** example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10055843/176769) also shows how to work with ROIs.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP description, it sounds like the OP just wants to automated way to crop an image into 6 pieces.

Google for "irfanview batch crop" or "ImageMagick batch crop"

If a more complex cropping logic/procedure is needed, then gfx library of the OP's language of choice should have a cropping function that they can code.

OpenCV would be an overkill for this task.

if OP insist on using OpenCV, then set the ROI

Mat image = imread("src_image_path");
Rect roi = Rect(x, y, w, h);
Mat image_roi = image(roi);

imwrite("dest_image_path", image_roi);