# copy a part of image with openCv c++

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing

I am using opencv and I want to create an image from a part of another image.

I didn't find a function that do that so I try to implement my Idea which consist of copying the image pixel by pixel but in vain I didn't get the result I am waiting for.

Any one has another Idea

Code:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
  IplImage * img =0;

  uchar *data;
  int i,j,k;
  int height,width,widthStep,nChannels;
  img=cvLoadImage(argv[1],3);
  height =img->height;
  width = img->width;
  widthStep= img->widthStep;
  nChannels = img->nChannels;
  data=(uchar*)img->imageData;
  IplImage* img1=cvCreateImage(cvSize(height/2,width/2),IPL_DEPTH_8U,nChannels);
  for(i=0;i<height/2;i++){
    for(j=0;j<width/2;j++){
      for(k=0;k<3;k++){
        img1->imageData[i*widthStep+j*nChannels]=data[i*widthStep+j*nChannels];
      }
    }
  }
  cvShowImage("image_Originale2",img1);
  cvWaitKey(0);
  cvReleaseImage(&img);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish can be done by setting a **ROI** (Region of Interest) on that image and copying that portion defined by the ROI to a new image.

You can see a [demo using `IplImage` on this post](http://areshopencv.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/region-of-interest-selection-roi.html).

These posts show uses of ROI to solve different scenarios:

- [MultiCrops in same image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073545/176769)
- [Setting ROI with mouse from a rectangle on a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881397/setting-roi-with-mouse-from-a-rectangle-on-a-video/10883266#10883266)
- [Put Image in contour (OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920178/put-image-in-contour-opencv/10920613#10920613)
- [IplImage inside IplImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10055573/176769)

It's important to note that your code is using the **C interface** of OpenCV. The C++ interface offers `cv::Mat`, which is the equivalent of `IplImage`. In other words, what you are looking for is a **C solution** to the problem.

Answer (score 34):

You should use `cv::Mat`'s copy constructor. It's much better than `IplImage`:

```
int x = 10,
    y = 20, 
    width = 200,
    height = 200;

Mat img1, img2;
img1 = imread("Lenna.png");
img2 = img1(Rect(x, y, width, height));
```

Comment: It's not better by definition, it's different; legacy OpenCV versus the 'new' C++ api. Indeed, but old IplImage stuff will be depreciated in OpenCV 3, and I advise everyone who reads this to switch to the new cv::Mat style.

Answer (score 5):

Using copy constructor :

```
cv::Mat whole = ...; // from imread or anything else
cv::Mat part(
   whole,
   cv::Range( 20, 220 ), // rows
   cv::Range( 10, 210 ));// cols
```

Answer (score 2):

Look up the [cvSetImageROI()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#setimageroi) function.

> Sets an image Region Of Interest (ROI) for a given rectangle.