# OpenCV Python face recognition only one face recognition

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, face-recognition

**Hi,Everyone** We are working on a face recognition application when ı run the code below, as you can see in the photo it works only in one face(red square) it doesnt scan other faces in the traning-data ı guess my predict function only run one time. dont in the loop.

Processed Image : [LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCiWZ.png)

```
 # coding: utf-8
 import cv2
 import os
 import numpy as np
 suclular = ["Bilinmeyen", "Veli Eroglu", "Ali Eroglu"]


 def detect_face(img):
     # ALGORİMA için Gri Yapıyoruz.
     gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     # yüz tanımlama için geereken haarcascade
     face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(
         'opencv-files/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml')
     faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
         gray, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5)  # YÜZ TANIMLAMA
     for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
         img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
     if (len(faces) == 0):
         return None, None  # Yuz bulunamazsa...
     (x, y, w, h) = faces[0]
     return gray[y:y + w, x:x + h], faces[0]

 face_recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
 face_recognizer.train(faces, np.array(labels))


 def draw_rectangle(img, rect):
     (x, y, w, h) = rect
     cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)


 def draw_text(img, text, x, y):
     cv2.putText(img, text, (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)


 def predict(test_img):
     img = test_img.copy()
     face, rect = detect_face(img)
     label, confidence = face_recognizer.predict(face)
     print(confidence)
     label_text = suclular[label]
     if confidence > 42 and confidence < 70:
         label_text = "Tespit Edilemedi."
         print(label_text)
     elif confidence > 70:
         label_text = "Bilinmiyor"
     draw_rectangle(img, rect)
     draw_text(img, label_text, rect[0], rect[1] - 5)

     return img


 print("Predicting images...")
 test_img1 = cv2.imread("test-data/test8jpg.jpg")
 predicted_img1 = predict(test_img1)
 print("Prediction complete")
 cv2.imshow("SONUC", cv2.resize(predicted_img1, (400, 500)))
 cv2.waitKey(0)
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
 cv2.waitKey(1)
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You prediction should be with in the for loop... You are only returning one face from your `detect_face` function which is the last face even though you are looping through each face and making a rectangle for each face... You should do something like this:

```
def predict_face(img):
     # ALGORİMA için Gri Yapıyoruz.
     gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     # yüz tanımlama için geereken haarcascade
     face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(
         'opencv-files/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml')
     faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
         gray, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5)  # YÜZ TANIMLAMA
     detected_faces = []
     i = 0
     for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
         img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
         detected_face = gray[y:y + w, x:x + h]
         label, confidence = face_recognizer.predict(detected_face)  # Prediction inside for loop
         draw_rectangle(img, faces[i])    # draw the red rectangles for every predicted face
         draw_text(img, label, x, y - 5)  # draw the predicted label on top of the box
         i += 1
```

- See the third line in for loop ... My prediction is inside the for loop
- Even draw the rectangles with in the for loop
- No need to store the rectangles and loop through them again to draw them
- Draw the prediction with in the for loop
- So you do everything in one function

Comment: ı try run the code because your code dont work. TRACEBACK               predicted_img1 = predict_face(test_img1)                                             draw_text(img, label, x, y - 5)  # draw the predicted label on top of the box                                                                                                   cv2.putText(img, text, (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation                                 Why ?

Comment: are you returning the `img` from `predict_face()` function ???.. which line are you exactly getting the error.... I think you are not returning the `img` thats why `predicted_img1` is None so its throwing you that error

Comment: yeah you're right i solve this problem that's works. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing the original image to the `predict()` function?
Once you've detected the two faces, you should pass each of them ([extracted from the original image using OpenCV functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529365/copy-a-part-of-image-with-opencv-c)) to the predict function.
In this way your algorithm will work and be faster.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i have a face detection app already
here it is

```html
#fdm:
import time
import cv2 as cv
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    
    parser.add_argument("-D", "--device", help='choose your input(availble: mp4 leave empty for camera)', default=0)
    parser.add_argument("-S", "--size", help='cap width', type=int, default=640)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
args = get_args()

global cap_device
cap_device = args.device
global size
size = args.size
mp_face_detection = mp.solutions.face_detection
cap_device = args.device
cap = cv.VideoCapture(cap_device)
with mp_face_detection.FaceDetection(model_selection=1, min_detection_confidence=0.5) as face_detector:
    frame_counter = 0
    fonts = cv.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        frame_counter += 1
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret is False:
            break
        rgb_frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=size)
        results = face_detector.process(rgb_frame)
        frame_height, frame_width, c = frame.shape
        if results.detections:
            for face in results.detections:
                face_react = np.multiply(
                    [
                        face.location_data.relative_bounding_box.xmin,
                        face.location_data.relative_bounding_box.ymin,
                        face.location_data.relative_bounding_box.width,
                        face.location_data.relative_bounding_box.height,
                    ],
                    [frame_width, frame_height, frame_width, frame_height]).astype(int)
                
                cv.rectangle(frame, face_react, color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=2)
                key_points = np.array([(p.x, p.y) for p in face.location_data.relative_keypoints])
                key_points_coords = np.multiply(key_points,[frame_width,frame_height]).astype(int)
        
        fps = frame_counter / (time.time() - start_time)
        cv.putText(frame,f"FPS: {fps:.2f}",(10, 30),cv.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX,0.7,(0, 255, 255),2,)
        key = cv.waitKey(1)
        if key == 27:
            break

        cv.imshow("face detection", frame)
    cap.release()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```